# Pass JSON object list to action

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a Model like this in my ASP.NET MVC 2 project,

```
public class HomeModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int HomeCount { get; set; }

        private List<string> _list;
        public List<string> List
        {
            get
            {
                if (_list == null)
                {
                    _list = new List<string>();
                }
                return _list;
            }
            set
            {
                _list = value;
            }
        }
        private List<ChildModel> _children;
        public List<ChildModel> Children
        {
            get
            {
                if (_children == null)
                {
                    _children = new List<ChildModel>();
                }
                return _children;
            }
            set
            {
                _children = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public class ChildModel
    {
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

and the script as

```
var obj = new Object();
            obj.Name = "MyName";
            obj.HomeCount = 56;

            obj.List = new Array();
            obj.List[0] = "AAA";
            obj.List[1] = "bbb";
            var child = new Object();
            child.Address = "ccc";
            obj.Children = new Array();
            obj.Children[0] = child;
            var child2 = new Object();
            child.Address = "ddd";
            obj.Children[1] = child2;

            jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true
            $.post('/Home/Test',obj, function (data) { });
```

My problem is even the string list is generated at the controller's action, the object list's count is 0. Can anyone tell how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

When you submit an object as jQuery's ajax payload, it's converted to key/value pairs of data. If this were $.get instead of $.post for example, you'd wind up with

?name=MyName&etc.

This article should get you what you're looking for:
http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2010/06/11/jquery-send-json-object-with-an-ajax-request/

I'd also recommend json/object literal notation here:

var obj = {
     Name: "MyName",
    HomeCount: 56,
    List:["AAA","bbb"],
    child:{
        Address: "ccc",
        Children:[
            //etc
        ]
    }
}

see json.org for specs, and jslint.com/jshint.com for validation.